# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos(x/\sqrt{n})^n = e^{-x^2/2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I am trying to prove the limit in the title.

We have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \cos^n\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{n \log\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)} $$

and I guess taking the Taylor expansion around $0$ of $\cos\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ will get us the $-\frac{1}{2}x^2$. Using continuity of $\log$, we find that

$$n \log\left(\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right) =  n \log\left( \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!} \left(\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^{k}\right) $$

What can we do next?

Comment: Just keep the first two terms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for $x\ne0$, $$n\ln\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}=n\cdot\frac{\ln\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}}{\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}-1}\cdot\frac{\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}-1}{\frac{x^2}n}\cdot\frac{x^2}{n}$$

Then, you can use that $\frac{\ln T}{T-1}\to 1$ as $T\to 1$ and that $\frac{\cos u-1}{u^2}\to-\frac12$ as $s\to 0$. Therefore $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}=\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot \frac{x^2}n\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}}{\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}-1}\right)\cdot\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\cos\frac x{\sqrt n}-1}{\frac{x^2}n}\right)=-\frac{x^2}2$$

For $x=0$ the sequence is constant.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\dfrac x{\sqrt n}=2y\implies n=\dfrac{x^2}{4y^2}\implies y\to0$

$$\lim_{y\to0}(\cos2y)^{x^2/4y^2}=\left(\lim_{y\to0}(1-2\sin^2y)^{-\frac1{2\sin^2y}}\right)^{-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{2x^2\sin^2y}{4y^2}}=?$$

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to write$$\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\cos\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{n}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\cos\tfrac{x}{\sqrt{n}}-1)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(-x^2/(2n))\\&=-x^2/2\end{align}$$using$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\cos y-1}{-y^2/2}=1.$$